# Apache Mahout - Learning Prerequisites

Tags: mahout

For a novice to machine learning, what are the learning prerequisites to using Apache Mahout in an efficient way?

I know that a committer to Mahout would need calculus, linear algebra, probability and machine learning before they can contribute anything useful. But does a "User" of Apache Mahout need all of this?

I'm asking this because learning/revising all of the above would take me ages..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mahout In Action provides a good overview of what you need to know to use Mahout.

Typically, scalable machine learning does not require advanced mathematics for use.  It may require serious math to develop, but not necessarily to use.

The primary requirement is that you really understand your data and its origins and what you want to do with it.  That understanding doesn't have to come all at once and can be developed over time.

Answer (score -2):

Try to Google the topics below:

1. [Programming Collaborative Intelligence](http://books.google.com/books/about/Programming_Collective_Intelligence.html?id=fEsZ3Ey-Hq4C&redir_esc=y)
2. Similarity calculation with vectors
3. What's the different between cluster and classification.